# Getting infinite loop instead of a value

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, do-while, typeid, typeinfo

This is the problem below.

I am getting an infinite loop instead of int type of data in the do-while loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()

{
    int in; // variable in;

    do //loop for check if variable get valid data
    {

        std::cout << "enter : ";

        std::cin >> in;

        if (typeid(in) == typeid(int()))
            break;
        else
            std::cout << "invalid input !! " << std::endl;
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between int and int(). In your program the following would hold: `typeid(in) == typeid(int)`.
You can further check via printing out `typeid(int()).name()`
As a sidenote, I am not sure, why you needed to wrap all your data into that while loop.

Comment: As other are saying, the infinite loop is due to `int` and `int()` being different types.
But actually that check has no meaning: `typeid(in)` is fixed  (i.e. it is `typeid(int)`), no matter what user will enter. after entering .e.g. `abc`, `in` is still an int

Comment: typeid(int()) and typeid(int) create two instance of typeid of same information. thats why equal to operation is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition

```
if (typeid(in) == typeid(int()))
```

will evaluate to false.

For it to evaluate to true you will need

```
if (typeid(in) == typeid(int))
```

[**Running sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/Byh3jZLwL)

But, as already said, if what you want is to check for correct inputs, this is not the way to go.

Comment: @JohnDing, granted, but it's not quite clear that is the purpose, it might be that the OP just wants to understand how to use this. I changed the answer, to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Although you use RTTI, the type of `in` is fixed at compile time. Plus, here you cannot directly compare the `typeid` of a `int` variable and a function type. They won't be the same. So such a design is nonsense. To check whether the input satisfy the requirement of integer input. Basically you have two ways:

1. Check whether the `failbit` of `cin` is set.
2. read a `string` instead and check whether each character in the string is digit.

Comment: So, why the condition fails and there is an infinite loop?

Comment: @Gupta I noticed my fault, I'll edit it later, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`typeid(in) == typeid(int())` is equivalent to `typeid(int) == typeid(int())` as `in` is a `int`.

`int()` is a signature of function: taking no parameter, and returning `int`.

So different than type `int`.

Way to check input validity is to check `std::cin` status.